# android - What changes required for play store app before uploading to Amazon AppStore

Tags: android, amazon-appstore

I am new to Amazon App Store.
My App is already there in the play store. Now i want to upload my app to amazon app store. For this,is any changes required for my application coding to support it for kindle fire family and upload my app to the Amazon App Store? I tried but it confusing me please can anyone help me

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking at the "submitting apps:details" and "submitting apps:binary info" in the [FAQ](https://developer.amazon.com/help/faq.html) and then be sure to read the entire thing.